IF ELSE statement in snowflake
Can someone please help me to debug why the following script cannot run in snowflake? It said it has syntax error inside. Thanks
DECLARE
    current_database STRING;
    current_schema STRING;
BEGIN
    current_database := CURRENT_DATABASE();
    current_schema := CURRENT_SCHEMA();

 IF current_database <> 'DEV' OR current_schema <> 'CONFIG' THEN
     RETURN 'WRONG SCHEMA SELECTED';
     ELSE RETURN 'GOOD'
 END IF;

END;


If needs PARENs, but the big kicker is your return 'good' is missing the semicolon:
DECLARE
    current_database STRING;
    current_schema STRING;
BEGIN
    current_database := CURRENT_DATABASE();
    current_schema := CURRENT_SCHEMA();

 IF (current_database <> 'DEV' OR current_schema <> 'CONFIG') THEN
     RETURN 'WRONG SCHEMA SELECTED';
     ELSE RETURN 'GOOD';
 END IF;

END;


It can also be shrank a bit more:
BEGIN
    let current_database string := CURRENT_DATABASE();
    let current_schema string := CURRENT_SCHEMA();

    IF (current_database <> 'DEV' OR current_schema <> 'CONFIG') THEN
        return 'WRONG SCHEMA SELECTED';
    END IF;
    
    return 'GOOD';
END;

or even to:
BEGIN
    IF (CURRENT_DATABASE() <> 'DEV' OR CURRENT_SCHEMA() <> 'CONFIG') THEN
        return 'WRONG SCHEMA SELECTED';
    END IF;
    
    return 'GOOD';
END;


Thanks for help. It works.
But now I have another question is  how do I make this BEGIN block embedded into my script. Since the schema validation is ensure I am in the right place to execute the following MERGE script.
Does it should look like
BEGIN
IF (CURRENT_DATABASE() <> 'DEV' OR CURRENT_SCHEMA() <> 'CONFIG') THEN
return 'WRONG SCHEMA SELECTED';
END IF;
MERGE statment
END;

I will propose another new page for my question. Thanks for help !! @Simeon

the SNOWFLAKE SCRIPTING block is a valid "block" if in the like you suggest after the check, you have a line that does a merge, then the block can as a whole be placed a SELECT 1; could be ran. (beside the edge cases of a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT)

At a minimum, your IF condition needs to be in parenthesis; IF ( ... )
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/if

I tried adding ; after GOOD and it worked.
enter image description here

Please provide the code block as text
